# Show that the Mobius strip is non-orientable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

The Mobius strip is the 2D manifold $M$ with the atlas of $n$ cubic charts $U_i$, $1 ≤ i ≤ n$, with coordinates $(x_i, y_i)$ satisfying $|x_i| <
1, |y_i| < 1$. Let $U_i^±$ be a part of $U_i$ defined by the condition $±x_i > 0$. Glue the domains $U_k^+$ and $U^-_{k+1}$ via transition functions $x_k = x_{k+1} +1$, $y_k = y_{k+1}$ for $1 ≤ k ≤ n − 1$. And glue $U_n^+$ with $U_1^−$ via $x_n = x_1 + 1$, $y_n = −y_1$.

Show that $M$ is connected and non-orientable.

I understand that in order to show that $M$ is not orientable, we need to show that the Jacobian of the transition function is neither strictly positive nor strictly negative on its domain. I'm thinking about looking at the Jacobian for different values of $n$ in order to see if I can find a pattern, but I'm not sure precisely how to do that.

Edit: We have been told that it is sufficient for us to prove that  $M$ is connected and non-orientable for $n=2$.

Comment: @OP: Do you know any homology?

Comment: @noctusraid I don't think so? I'm not entirely familiar with the word. I have a basic understanding about charts, transition maps, atlases, manifolds, orientability, and homeomorphisms.

Comment: Nevermind then! You could have computed the cellular homology of the Mobius strip to answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We say that M is orientable if and only if there exists an atlas $A = \{(U_{\alpha}, \phi_{\alpha})\}$ such that $\textrm{det}(J(\phi_{\alpha} \circ \phi_{\beta}^{-1}))> 0$, if it is defined.

Assume that it is orientable. Then we would be able to define a map, $x\to n_x$ that sends $x$ to a unit vector normal to the surface in such a way that the map is continuous. Since $M$ is two-dimensional and embedded in 3-space, this map is determined by the value at a single point (because you have two choices, one in each direction from the surface). Now observe that if you follow a loop around the strip, the value of $n_x$ changes sign when you return to $x$ from the other side.